# Create a hardcoded "mapping table" in Trino SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a query (several CTEs) that get data from different sources. The output has a column `name`, but I would like to map this nameg to a more user-friendly name.

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | buy |
| 2 | send |
| 3 | paid |

I would like to hard code somewhere in the query (in another CTE?) a mapping table. Don't want to create a separate table for it, just plain text.

name_map=[('buy', 'Item purchased'),('send', 'Parcel in transit'), ('paid', 'Charge processed')]

So output table would be:

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item purchased |
| 2 | Parcel in transit |
| 3 | Charge processed |

In Trino I see the function `map_from_entries` and `element_at`, but don't know if they could work in this case.

I know "case when" might work, but if possible, a mapping table would be more convenient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super interesting idea, and I think I got it working:

```
with tmp as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('1', 'buy'),
                  ('2', 'send'),
                  ('3', 'paid')) as t(id, name)
)
SELECT element_at(name_map, name) as name
FROM tmp
JOIN (VALUES map_from_entries(
    ARRAY[('buy', 'Item purchased'),
          ('send', 'Parcel in transit'),
          ('paid', 'Charge processed')])) as t(name_map) ON TRUE
```

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| Item purchased |
| Parcel in transit |
| Charge processed |

To see a bit more of what's happening, we can look at:

```
SELECT *, element_at(name_map, name) as name
```

| id | name | name_map | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buy | {buy=Item purchased, paid=Charge processed, send=Parcel in transit} | Item purchased |
| 2 | send | {buy=Item purchased, paid=Charge processed, send=Parcel in transit} | Parcel in transit |
| 3 | paid | {buy=Item purchased, paid=Charge processed, send=Parcel in transit} | Charge processed |

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it's certainly an interesting idea.

Comment: Very nice. I actually removed the first part, where you map numbers to names and just kept the second part of the CTE, since later I'll make joins to other tables. Great, didn't know how to use those functions. Thanks!!

Comment: The first part is just creating the temp table of your data, so that it actually runs as is. You'd only use the `element_at()` and `JOIN` your mapped entries with an existing table~

Answer (score 4):

As a simpler alternative to the other answer, you don't actually need to create an intermediate map using `map_from_entries` and look up values using `element_at`. You can just create an inline mapping table with `VALUES` and use a regular `JOIN` to do the lookups:

```sql
WITH mapping(name, description) AS (
    VALUES
        ('buy', 'Item purchased'),
        ('send', 'Parcel in transit'),
        ('paid', 'Charge processed')
)
SELECT description
FROM t JOIN mapping ON t.name = mapping.name
```

(The query assumes your data is in a table named `t` that contains a column named `name` to use for the lookup)

Comment: This is great! I got stuck on using `map_from_entries` and `element_at` since they were suggested, but this does the same thing in a much cleaner way.

Comment: As far as performance goes, how does this compare to using `CASE` statements, or does the optimizer treat them similarly/the same?